# UPDATE, but DELETE upon DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: mysql

Is there a simple way to execute something like `"UPDATE... ON DUPLICATE KEY DELETE"`?

Let say I have this, with no duplicates on color + pattern:

```
| style  | color | pattern |
----------------------------
| spice  | red   | dots    |
| sea    | blue  | dots    |
```

If someone changes the "spice" style's color to "blue", I want it to see that there will be a duplicate, and delete the duplicate record. The result would be only 1 record:

```
| style  | color | pattern |
----------------------------
| sea    | blue  | dots    |
```

EDIT: I'm pretty sure there is no actual syntax like the above, but was thinking there might be some combination of commands or joins that would produce the desired result.

Comment: If you have a unique key on the color and pattern together it probably would throw an error you could catch on the update

Comment: Yeah. But you also get a duplicate key error on INSERT, and there are ways to accommodate that like INSERT IGNORE or ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, so I was just wondering if there was a similar workaround for this that would not require SQL 1 -> error check -> SQL 2.

Comment: I don't know of any such syntax

Answer (score 0):

Just do two statements. Do the DELETE first, then it won't  bother doing the UPDATE as you deleted the row already.

```
DELETE mytable WHERE style = 1 AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE color = 'blue' AND style <> 1 );
UPDATE mytable SET color = 'blue' WHERE style = 1;
COMMIT;
```